# How to enable AAD authentication for storage account listing?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-storage-account

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/list?tabs=dotnet&tryIt=true&source=docs#storageaccountlist) tutorial for listing all of the storage accounts in my subscription. Previously I used `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` but this is now deprecated so that's the reason for switching to the new approach suggested by Microsoft. I had no issues with `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` but now I can't authenticate against my `DefaultAzureCredential` that is later on used as an input of `ArmClient`. I have my Managed Identity switched ON for my App Service that contains the code that calls the function for listing storage accounts but still doesn't work. I spent my last two days in searching for the right permissions and how to set them but failed. Has someone used this functionality in cloud and what did you do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce to the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one web application with same code and published it to **Azure** successfully like below:

[image]

When I checked Portal, webjob created in Azure Web App with **same name** as below:

[image]

Now, I ran the above webjob by clicking `Run` where state changed to **Running** like below:

[image]

When I checked **Logs** tab from above screen, I got `AuthorizationFailed` error in response like this:

[image]

> Note that, `DefaultAzureCredential` will automatically detect
> authentication method based on your app's configuration. If you
> enabled system-managed identity, make sure to assign proper **RBAC role** to it.

To list storage accounts in subscription, you can assign `Storage Blob Data Reader` or `Reader` role to **managed identity** under subscription like this:

*Go to Azure Portal -> App Services -> Your App Service -> Identity -> Azure role assignments*

[image]

I selected `Storage Blob Data Reader`  role with **Subscription** as scope like below:

[image]

After few minutes, role assigned successfully to **managed identity** like this:

[image]

When I ran webjob now, I got **response** with `Succeeded` message like below:

[image]

To run the **same code** from local environment via Visual Studio, sign in with **valid** user account that is used by `DefaultAzureCredential` as authentication method.

In my case, I ran `az login` command and signed in with **admin** account like this:

[image]

When I ran **same code** now to list storage accounts, I got response with resource id successfully like below:

```cs
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage;

TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();

ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);

string subscriptionId = "9c80bd38-bcc9-4ccb-8afe-xxxxxxxxxx";
ResourceIdentifier subscriptionResourceId = SubscriptionResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId);
SubscriptionResource subscriptionResource = client.GetSubscriptionResource(subscriptionResourceId);

await foreach (StorageAccountResource item in subscriptionResource.GetStorageAccountsAsync())
{

    StorageAccountData resourceData = item.Data;
    // for demo we just print out the id
    Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
}

Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded");
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[How to authenticate .NET applications with Azure services | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line#exploring-the-sequence-of-defaultazurecredential-authentication-methods)

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I did everything as you explained, however nothing significantly changed. I set up as said and seen here: https://i.imgur.com/EYaqFF9.png. But this is still the result I get: https://i.imgur.com/vs61j1x.png. Locally it gets a list of storage accounts, "globally" or deployed it doesn't. I checked the logs, no errors were thrown and the request had a status 200 which is kind of weird :/ My subscription id is taken from an App Config both locally and deployed so I think that we're fine when it comes to this.

Comment: Could you include how you are running code and retrieving console output in App Service?

Comment: Sure. Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/8xzmXDjP and the console output: **2023-03-10 09:25:31 XXX-API GET /api/xx/storageAccounts X-ARR-LOG-ID=xx 443 - xx.xx.xx.xx**. Weirdly enough, it gives me 443 status code. The status 200 I reported in the previous comment was related to the swagger client because I invoke the endpoint from swagger. By googling 443 status code, I get that Error 443 / 404 means that the website is gone.

Comment: Do you have any idea what could be the case for 443? @Sridevi

Comment: Not sure what might be the problem here. Usually assigning proper RBAC roles to the managed identity resolves authentication issues. Will get back to you in some time if I found any solution.